OpenAI and MathOverflow?
The agreement between SO and OpenAI seems to have resulted some ill humour.  Does MO plan to follow?

Related - to some extent: How do we fit in with Stack Exchange’s new AI agreement with Google?

What do you mean by 'follow'?

Also related: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5669/at-what-point-should-mo-recognise-it-needs-to-leave-stack-exchange-inc

It is not clear from the announcements if the agreement covers only Stack Overflow the website, or the whole Stack Exchange network, including MO. I guess the question if we 'plan to follow' assumes the first scenario.

@DavidRoberts -- I mean establish some agreement with an AI company to monetise the site's question and answers.  It is my understanding that MO is independent of SE (though using the same site software and user licence), if that was mistaken then this question is moot of course.

I think 'plan' is putting the cart before the horse; as far as I can tell, we're all just getting up to speed on this AI agreement business -- consequently, I doubt there are any 'plans' as such one way or another. If you mean to ask if it's possible we'll end up doing something like that in the future I think that's a good question; I would personally be against it, but can't speak for the community at large.

This isn't really an answer as such, but just to confirm:  there are no current plans to do anything in response to this agreement (we have no information about our involvement in it beyond the press release; in particular, it's genuinely unclear how MathOverflow will be involved).  We certainly have no plans to seek out a side deal or any monetization of the site.  We'd like to hear from people about whether any response is warranted.

Could you guys (moderators/site rulers) perhaps inquire as to the deets on how MO is involved with these shenanigans as they currently stand?

@AlecRhea: Still no response... And MO moderators should certainly try to get a black-and-white statement that their content will not be rudely scraped and sold off (illegally) to OpenAI.
