# Can we get rid of the "featured on meta" main meta links?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, sidebar, community-bulletin

As you know, MathOverflow has a special status in the Stack Exchange family, and (by a special agreement) it doesn't display any kind of ads nor links to the hot network questions in the sidebar.

Would it be possible to remove also the links to the global meta questions in the "featured on meta" top-right sidebar? For instance currently I would remove the two top links, leaving only the third one.

[image]

I don't find them particularly useful. To me they are just fluff and they make *our* meta questions stand out less; they take up premium space in the top right part of the page "above the fold".

Also, under a suitable interpretation of the expression, arguably they can be considered "internal advertisements", and so they would be forbidden by the [agreement](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-Rx93qiEH3t9wAwsyvuVzjawF62X6OgI/view) between MO and SE, which can be found [in this answer by François G. Dorais♦](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/969/who-owns-mathoverflow/970#970). The relevant part is:

> 5. It is understood that MathOverflow shall consider in the future the placement of certain announcement services like job listing in the future. Stack Exchange shall not run advertisements, including internal advertisements, on MathOverflow 2.0 (or any subsequent version thereof), without specific and advance written consent of the MathOverflow.

EDIT: everything I wrote applies also to the SE blog entries:

[image]

EDIT: and yet another example of blatant self-advertising that does not do us users any good:

[image]

Comment: The links are actually useful from time to time, for example when they discuss planned changes to the software. It’s not always the Unicorn Zoo nonsense.

Comment: Unless I messed up something when creating the SEDE query, here is the list of questions on [meta.se] which had the (featured) tag at some point: https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/revision/1066745/1318346/questions-which-had-the-given-tag-including-the-editor-who-added-it?tagname=featured There are also other entries which appear in the CB, such as  blog entries. See also: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/community-bulletin/info and [What criteria are used to select the links that appear in the community bulletin sidebar block?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130621).

Comment: Here is a bit simpler query (the difference is that it shows the user who posted the question rather than the user who added the featured tag): https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/revision/1099692/1357576/posts-which-had-the-given-tag-in-the-past

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned in [Emil Jeřábek's comment](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4339/can-we-get-rid-of-the-featured-on-meta-main-meta-links#comment21003_4339) (which quickly gained several upvotes), at least *some* of the "network-wide stuff" (Meta Stack Exchange posts, blog posts) can be useful also for MathOverflow users.

Let me suggest an alternative proposal to the complete removal of those links from the community bulletin.

**Suggestion.** Reorder the links in the community bulletin in such way that the posts which have importance for MathOverflow (posts from MathOverflow Meta, election announcements, etc.) would be at the top and posts originating from Meta Stack Exchange (and blog posts) would be below them.

If the main concern is that the posts from Meta MathOverflow get less attention because they are at the bottom, this might help a bit. This was a suggestion which was proposed by Meta Andrew T. when I recently asked on Meta Stack Exchange about another suggestion related to the community bulletin: [Allow local mods to remove items from community bulletin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333007#333033). (Perhaps the answers posted there are worth reading in connection with this discussion.)

<sup>I suppose that it might make sense to post a proposal like this on Meta Stack Exchange. However, I thought it might be reasonable to see what MO users think about this - since a discussion about community bulletin started on this meta anyway. I do not plan to post two feature requests concerning the community bulletin on Meta Stack Exchange so soon after each other - but if somebody else decides to make a feature request along these lines, I certainly have no objections to that.</sup>

Comment: As a side not I will mention that the posts from [meta.se] are displayed in the community bulletin only on the main site, not on meta.