# Happy tenth anniversary! How did you celebrate?

Tags: discussion, recent-activity

Question 1 was a test question posted about ten years ago from this one (give or take about an hour). There's been a bit going on since then with the main forum.  This post is a place for celebrants to respond with what they did.  If others want to leave personal reflections on MathOverflow's 10th anniversary, answer posts on that are also welcome.

So how do you/did you celebrate MathOverflow?

Gerhard "The Party Isn't Over Yet" Paseman, 2019.09.28.

Comment: If we take the posting of [Question Number 1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1/ignore-this-question) as a basis, the posting of this comment marks a little more precisely the 10th anniversary of MathOverflow!

Comment: @user142929 How is your comment relevant to Gerhard's post or MO's anniversary?

Comment: I deleted it, it was just my feedback about the question @YemonChoi

Comment: I'd be interested to hear or read of any media coverage of MO that this anniversary may have given rise to. (Maybe this warrants a separate question.)

Comment: I would too. Gerhard "Doesn't Handle MathOverflow Media Relations" Paseman, 2019.09.30.

Comment: While we are celebrating, the Titanic is sinking. First the licensing issue (https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333089/ https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333615/ https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333678/), and now the firing on a whim of one of the most respected moderators on multiple sites that resulted in mass resignation of others (https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/ https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334015/ etc., just see the meta home page https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If the metaphor is apt @Emil , where are the lifeboats? I don't downplay the concerns: MathOverflow suffers from analogous problems and things should be done. Indeed, my hope is to bring the community together to celebrate, to acknowledge and consider, and then make a plan for moving forward. But I don't see this as a sinking ship. Gerhard "Are You Getting On Board?" Paseman, 2019.10.01.

Comment: Well, our lifeboat as it were is Section 7 of the [migration agreement](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/970). While I’m not saying that matters already got to the point where it would become necessary to invoke it, we should watch the developments closely to stay informed. And, let me stress that we are not watching it from outside; at this time we are an integral part of the SE network, and most of the contentious issues directly apply to MO (the mandatory arbitration clause last year, now the possibly illegal relicensing, the apparently coming update of the code of conduct, ...).

Comment: @StefanKohl your comment is accurate on the second!

Comment: Yes, and some how I was off an hour. Gerhard "Not Sure How That Happened" Paseman, 2019.10.07.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Maybe you didn't take daylight saving time into account?

Answer (score 20):

We had a great meet-up in Utrecht. Here is a picture:

[image]

From left to right: Renee Hoekzema, Marina Logares, Joey van Langen, Aldo Witte, Luca Accornero (in the back), Alvaro del Pino Gomez (in the front), Thomas Rot.

We had some interesting discussions regarding the past and future of mathoverflow!

Answer (score 12):

The group hosted by Alec had a great time with Anton, Anna, Anton, Peter, Gjergji, Larry, Cheryl, and Gerhard attending. (Photo and a few more details to come.) As with any group of people predisposed to thinking, the conversations touched on politics and philosophy, and some high and low points of the forum were mentioned. There were also some minor acrobatics and a lovely selection of appetizers. And a toast!

Gerhard "Anniversary Alliteration Is Already Attenuating" Paseman, 2019.09.29.

Comment: Mmm... toast. Did you have it with butter?

Comment: "Photo and a few more details to come." Nudge.

Answer (score 5):

I celebrated [over at my blog](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2019/09/28/test-your-intuition-40-what-are-we-celebrating-and-answer-to-tyi39/) (and will probably continue doing so during the year).

[image]